# UIElement.FlowDirection not implemented by is missing the "NotImplemented" attribute

Tags: uno-platform

UIElement.FlowDirection is [not implemented](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/implemented/windows-ui-xaml-controls-toggleswitch.html), but is missing the 'NotImplemented' attribute

Comment: It seems like it is marked with `NotImplemented` - see here: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/17605edbfab824283f3051bb39943ef7b18f3f00/src/Uno.UI/Generated/3.0.0.0/Windows.UI.Xaml/FrameworkElement.cs#L154 . Where do you see this behavior please?

Comment: Thanks for follow up. Thing is I don't see a warning in VS output for ToggleSwitch.FlowDIrection like I e.g. see for warning Uno0001: Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackageOperation.Move is not implemented in Uno

Comment: Can you please report it on Uno GitHub as an issue? It surely should be underlined and show warning, so that is quite curious.